# x86 Assembly Programming (GAS Syntax): What reigsters are the variables defined in the data section stored in?

Tags: assembly, memory, x86, global-variables, cpu-architecture

When I define the variables in the `.data` section such as the following:

```
.data
    a:
        .long 55

    b:
        .long 43
```

Which register(s) are `a` and `b` stored in (regarding the x86 computer architecture)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of them. They're stored in memory instead, and if you need them in a register, then you have to move their values there yourself.